# Take a range of cells from a Google spreadsheet

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Coding noob here, trying to learn...

I'm trying to take a range of cells in one google spreadsheet (not contiguous to any page/sheet border), convert the range to pdf, then email the pdf as an email attachment to a specified address. I can use a prewritten addin, but then I won't learn. A person only learns by asking questions.

I googled for answers, and got to this website (https://ctrlq.org/code/19869-email-google-spreadsheets-pdf). Trouble is, this script sends all of the sheets in a zip file. I don't want to do this. I just want to send, as a pdf, a range of selected cells located in only the first sheet and as a pdf, NOT a zip file.

My almost nonexistent javascript education tells me that my script uses the following code snippet to obtain the relevant data:
(Obviously, I might be wrong...)

```
// Get the currently active spreadsheet URL (link)
// Or use SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("<<SPREADSHEET URL>>");
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

I don't know if I've got the correct snippet, which is why I included the URL of its source. Anyhow, I simply want to send a range starting at row 2 column 3 and ending at row 31 column 12. 7 days later, I want to use another script to send a different range.

How can I modify this script to achieve my goal?

Thanks to everyone who can help!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The [Google Apps Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/) Is a good starting point. If you check the reference for [ranges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) you will notice that there is no method to get the range as a pdf. There isn't one either for sheets, only for whole spreadsheets, so you'll need to create a spreadsheet copy that contains only that range and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand what you are asking for and what it's really called.

As noted in the comment by [Robin Gertenbach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5426909/robin-gertenbach) you should look at the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) first. Only after you have exhausted the information there should you look elsewhere for code snippets etc. The reason I am saying this is that a range is most likely not what you think it is. The range object itself is not data you need but is a class that you can use to obtain the information instead.

For example if you want values you would do something like `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValues()` which would return an 2 array of string values. However, there is no such method to output a string of characters as a pdf. Logically a PDF is a document, so to get a PDF you need to export a document. The lowest document type is the actual spreadsheet and in the documentation you can see that [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getAs(String))

Anything else you can think off will come from Javascript and not Google Apps Script, so that is where you could look. The only alternative here is to create a new spreadsheet and save it as a pdf, then delete the spreadsheet.

The snippet you have is simply creating a variable with the entire spreadsheet as the object.