# Send email with an specific range attached in pdf

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, export, pdf-generation

I am doing a program in which I would like to press a button and be able to send by email the information of two specific sheets as attachments in PDF, which I would also like to save it in a folder in my Drive to keep the information organize
I have checked some of your information but can't do the PDF part

```
function sendEmail(){

   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   
   var ss = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()
 
   var NoInf =ss.getRange(10, 11).getValue();
   
   var Email = ss.getRange(12, 15).getValue();
   
   var propietario =  ss.getRange(10, 7).getValue();
   var Paciente = ss.getRange(11,7).getValue();
  
   var TipoInforme = ss.getSheetName()
 
   var Imagen = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Imagenes'),true);
  
   var Asunto =  NoInf + " - " + TipoInforme + " - " + propietario + " - " +Paciente;
  
   var Mensaje = "Anexo a la presente envío informe: " + '\n\n' + "No de Informe: " + NoInf; 

   MailApp.sendEmail(Email, Asunto, Mensaje) 
  
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I have checked some of your information"? and by "can't do the PDF part?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/40493324/1595451

Comment: I meant that I saw a couple of question related to export to PDF a spreadsheet, however I'm not sure if the actually will do what I need.
What I would like to do is send the email with two attachments in PDF which are two specifics sheets of my spreadsheet. 
One with data and the other will contain images

Comment: Please try those solutions that you found to be sure if they actually do what you need. If you need help to test them, [edit] your question to make it specific on what kind of help do you need.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment I understand that you want to send two Sheets as PDF in an email attachment. If that is correct, then you can use a code like the following one.

```js
function sendMail() {
  var spreadsheet1 = DriveApp.getFileById(
    '{MY FIRST SPREADSHEET ID}');
  var spreadsheet2 = DriveApp.getFileById(
    '{MY SECOND SPREADSHEET ID}');

  MailApp.sendEmail('{EMAIL TO}', '{EMAIL SUBJECT}',
    '{MESSAGE BODY}', {
      name: '{MY NAME}',
      attachments: [spreadsheet1.getAs(MimeType.PDF), spreadsheet2.getAs(
        MimeType.PDF)]
    });
}
```

In this example the Sheets are opened by [`DriveApp.getFileById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid) and later attached as PDF by using [`File.getAs()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getascontenttype). Please, don't hesitate to ask me to further clarify.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation is very useful, however I have another question.
In my case there is a spreadsheet with several sheets, I would like to be able to send two specific sheets, I suppose according with your explanation that I have to created first to individual spreadsheet with each sheet and then follow the code you send me??? I that case how can I created a copy of my actual spreadsheet with only the sheet I choose?

Comment: Hi there @HenriqueArevalo! You are right on your thinking, because exporting the spreadsheet as a PDF will include every single sheet on it.